# Is it possible to Flash firmware in nrf51/nRF52 from another MCU (like STM32) over UART interface?

Tags: stm32, firmware, nrf51

I need to flash nrf51 firmware from STM32. STM32 connected to nrf51, which will receive binary for nrf51 also and then it should be able to flash that in nrf51.

Is there any existing sample code for above?. I need more details.

Comment: Write a bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Yes technically this is possible however it wont be straightforward at all (especially given that you are using the nRF51 which is an old chip with limited flash). As far as I'm aware, nordic don't have a full example for this (especially from MCU to MCU part). If there's another way for you to do the upgrade, then I suggest you do that. However if you MUST perform an upgrade from STM32 to nRF51, then you need to get very familiar with Nordic's bootloader structure and their secure DFU. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [Firmware update over UART](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/70274/firmware-update-over-uart-interface)
- [Updating nRF52 from another nRF52 over UART](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/guides/short-range-guides/b/software-development-kit/posts/getting-started-with-nordics-secure-dfu-bootloader#h108sjziaxo3m81rkgr1has5r1d72qtu)
- [nRF SDK Bootloader Description](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v12.0.0%2Flib_bootloader.html)